# Does English have words that are clearly masculine or feminine that do not form pairs or are proper nouns?

Tags: natural-gender

While English does not have gender in the same way a Romance language does, it is still obviously able to define masculine and feminine concepts.
But words that are clearly masculine or feminine in the language often come in pairs (e.g. father - mother, woman - man, daughter - son, she - he) or are proper nouns such as names (e.g. Mary, Michael, John).
Are there words that imply an obvious natural gender, but do not fit the two categories?

Comment: “Ship” (and by analogy “car”) is often referred as ‘she’, and that's all. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ship#Usage_notes

Comment: This is as much a social as a linguistic question. A hundred years ago or so, _judge_, _soldier_ and _doctor_ were masculine.

Comment: @ColinFine Afemale doctor is a doctoress (or doctrix?), but what are the female versions of the other ones?

Comment: That's my point @VladimirF: as requested by Sodalite, they were gendered words which didn't have a pair, because they were inevitably masculine. (Doctoress existed but was extremely rare, because its referent was almost non-existent). Today none of them is specific as to gender.

Comment: Now I see soldieress and judgess exist as well. Somehow I thought it would clash with the plural "judges". In my language the female words for these professions are completely ordinary words. A judgess does not have to be a literal lawyer professional but someone who judges somthing or someone.

Answer (score 1):

There are professions ending in "man", which implies masculinity, and do not have official feminine equivalents, e.g. "fisherman". There is also "butler" (masculine) and "maid" (feminine) that fit your requirements as long as you don't consider them a pair.

Whether something implies masculinity or femininity is subjective, but a few that come to mind for this native English speaker are:

- "Demon" (masculine)
- "Banshee" (feminine)
- "Grizzled" (masculine) (see [HOW TO USE GRIZZLED IN A SENTENCE](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/grizzled) on this page and notice that it always describes a man)
- "Fair" adj. meaning beautiful (feminine)

Comment: I think you're on to something, especially with adjectives. There's handsome, chivalrous, gallant, gentlemanly, etc. At the same time, I think that nouns like policeman are becoming less and less gender associated despite their ending. But it can still apply to profession that phased out. Knight comes to mind. Mythology is also a good call. Other examples I can come up with: siren, gorgon, leprechaun, harpy, troll, selkie.

Comment: ‘Policewoman’ is definitely a word (though WPC may be more common in the UK, and gender-neutral ‘police officer’ would be preferred in the US). ‘Demon’ isn’t exclusively masculine to me either, and a fair young man is fine to me as well, but a banshee definitely is female (the _ban-_ part being from Irish _bean_ meaning ‘woman’). @Sodalite ‘Handsome’ is common enough for women, though of course the associations it conjures up are somewhat different (more aligned with strength and vigour than conventional good looks).

Comment: in principle one could have female butler. A butler has a very different role in a staffed household than a maid, the male equivalent of which is a valet (traditionally pronounced with the final t). Contrary to common belief, Jeeves is actually Bertie Wooster's valet, not his butler (his home in London is far too small to necessitate a full staff or a butler, and so he only has his "personal gentleman's gentleman")

Answer (score 0):

The main question is whether there are any words of English which on purely linguistic grounds *must* refer to a male, or a female. You presumably aware that this binary categorization is non-obvious and controversial. The majority of English speakers have a construct "male" and "female", assignments on which there isn't 100% agreement. So I assume you mean "what would most speakers conclude", ignoring the minority. Most speakers would conclude that "sister" refers to a female and "brother" refers to a male. 50 years ago, most speakers would conclude that "nurse, teacher" refer to a "female", and "coach, doctor" refer to a "male". Nowadays, you are more likely to get an argument if you claim that "doula" refers to a female, despite the etymological Greek feminine suffix.

Briefly, there was a construction "male nurse", but there is no suffix that can be used to linguistically entail a "gender". Compounding with *he-* is possible. The suffix -*ess* is conventionally used to explicitly limit the interpretation to "female", but it is only used in a limited set of words, [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ess#English) are some examples. They include "snakess", which strikes be a bizarre but it might exist in old literature. There are also female-referring suffixes for agent nouns, *-ix, -trix*; you can construct compounds like *policewoman*, *she-wolf* but I've only seen the later construction applied to a female human metaphoricaly. "Judgewoman, she-judge, judgess" would be socially extremely bizarre, but not ungrammatical. It's also not ungrammatical to use "actress" to refer to a male, it's just unconventional.